# What does someone mean by dynamically created structure when talking about the C language?

Tags: c, coding-style

If someone is talking about solving a problem with the C programming language, and they say that dynamically created structures is the way to go, what are they likely to be referring to? Is there another name for this perhaps?

Comment: Dynamic memory allocations in C usually refers to the use of malloc to set aside memory for objects the programmer wishes to control the lifetime of themselves.  The memory is available to the process until it is freed.

Comment: That may well be what they are referring to, if it helps I have a copy from the assignment sheet that may clarify:

You may use any programming environment available to you, but your program must conform to ‘C’
language standards as stated below.

**This assignment MUST be solved using dynamically created structures.**

PLEASE NOTE: We require you to all work using constructions which are valid in ANSI ‘C’ (1989) or
ANSI ‘C’ (1999) and not to use any extra extensions which the gcc or other ‘C’ compilers might provide.

Comment: @FelixFarquharson is there more context to the question? will help.

Comment: @FelixFarquharson, it looks like your assignment is saying to use `malloc`, but it is also saying to use `free` to avoid memory leaks.  By restricting you to C89/99 then you have to learn to do this work rather than let some compilers do it for you.  I.e. builds good programming habits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C allows you to allocate new memory while a program is running according to your needs (that's why is referred as "dynamical allocation").

For example: you have a very basic structure, a linked list, but you don't know how many nodes are required during the execution of your program. So in your code you declare that every time you need to store a new node in the list, the program must take this ***x*** amount of memory and allocate a new node (that will be attached to the existing list)

```
typedef struct {
    int datum;
    Node *next;
} Node;
```

then later on you can cay:

```
Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node);
```

In the same fashion you can free memory at run time:

```
free(new_node);
```

Comment: Huh?  Almost *every* modern programming language lets you allocate new memory while the program is running.

Comment: And for the love of sanity, ***do NOT cast the screwed poor `void *` return value of `malloc()`!!!***

Comment: @MatteoD, do NOT believe everything you are told to do.  Casting the return value is an OK thing to do.  Some programmers agree with this, others don't.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment requires that you use dynamic memory allocation for your data structures. Your program may not use statically allocated memory, that is, for example `int array[65536];`. Instead all these needs to be allocated on demand using the `malloc/calloc/realloc` (and supposedly be freed using the `free`).

Answer (score 0):

If your question is `How to create structure dynamically?`

Without knowing what you want to ask, I am just giving an answer, assuming you are asking about this only.

A dynamic data structure is a data structure that changes in size as a program needs it to by allocating and de-allocating memory from the heap -- a term used to describe unused memory available to the central processing unit(CPU) at any given time. A dynamic data structure lets a programmer control precisely how much memory is consumed by his or her program. When a dynamic data structure created in the C programming language allocates blocks of memory from the heap, it uses pointers to link those blocks together into a data structure of some kind. The data structure will return a block of memory to the heap when it doesn't need it any longer. This system of recycling memory blocks makes a program's use of memory very efficient.